# Help with ice cream cake

Tags: cake

I'm making an ice cream cake for my brothers birthday. I was putting the ice cream on the first layer of cake and put it in the freezer. I couldn't finish putting the icecream on because it was melting, I tried putting more ice cream on it 15 minutes later but it was melting all over the place. I put it in the freezer again. I think at the beginning my ice cream was way too soft. How do I fix this?? Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Is this homemade ice cream?

Comment: Was the cake warm when you added the ice cream? You might try chilling it once it's cooled after baking.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a malfunctioning freezer; this is why ice cream melted overnight in it.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for coming back to report what happened. There is no need to be ashamed because a cake didn't work. You can be sure that all the famous cooks in the world have ruined dozens of cakes in their lives, this is how everybody learns. I wish you a nice celebration despite the melted cake!

Comment: To the other users: I considered converting this to a comment, but in fact the OP recognized their problem and gave the correct answer - the cake must have caused trouble because of the malfunctioning freezer. So I see this post as an answer by our standards.